# multidimentional array of strings in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a text file like:

[image: sample file]

[edit] the number of line is unknown, it could be hundreds of lines.

How would I store them in a multidimensional array? I want my array to look like:

```
sample(0)(0) = "--------"
sample(0)(1) = "Line1"
..and so on
sample(1)(0) = "--------"
sample(1)(3) = "Sample 123"
..and so on
```

What I have done so far was to open the file and store in a 1-dimentional array:

```
logs = File.ReadAllLines("D:\LOGS.TXT")
```

I have tried creating an Array of string like:

```
Dim stringArray as String()()
stringArray = New String(varNumber0)(varNumber1)
```

But it returns and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadLines`/`File.ReadAllLines` to get the lines and a simple `For Each`-loop to fill a `List(Of List(Of String))`. Then you can use

```
list.Select(Function(l) l.ToArray()).ToArray()
```

to get the `String()()` (jagged array):

```
Dim lines = File.ReadLines("D:\LOGS.TXT")
Dim list As New List(Of List(Of String))
Dim current As List(Of String)
For Each line As String In lines.SkipWhile(Function(l) Not l.TrimStart.StartsWith("----------"))
    If line.TrimStart.StartsWith("----------") Then
        current = New List(Of String)
        list.Add(current)
    Else
        current.Add(line)
    End If
Next
Dim last = list.LastOrDefault()
If last IsNot Nothing Then
    If Not current Is last AndAlso current.Any() Then
        list.Add(current)
    ElseIf Not last.Any() Then
        list.Remove(last) ' last line was ("----------")'
    End If
End If

Dim stringArray As String()() = list.Select(Function(l) l.ToArray()).ToArray()
```

If you want to include the `---------` in the array at the first position:

```
For Each line As String In lines.SkipWhile(Function(l) Not l.TrimStart.StartsWith("----------"))
    If line.TrimStart.StartsWith("----------") Then
        current = New List(Of String)
        current.Add(line)
        list.Add(current)
    Else
        current.Add(line)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this but you need to customize according to you

```
    Dim mArray(10,10) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For I=0 to 10
      For J=0 to 10
        For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
            mArray(i,j) = cmdReader.Item(line)
        Next
       Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use declaration like this (this is just a generic)

```
    Dim dim1 As Integer = 0
    Dim dim2 As Integer = 0
    Dim strings(,) As String

    Do

        dim1 = NewDimensionNumberFromFile
        dim2 = NewSecondDimensionNumberFromFile

        ReDim Preserve strings(dim1, dim2)

        strings(dim1, dim2) = ValueFromfile

    Loop While (Not EOF()) 'this will determine
```